# MongoDb - How to Collect documents of a Collection which are realted to other Collection?

Tags: mongodb

iam New to Mongo Technology but I can convey the Question what Iam searching for .

Example:-  I have a **Restaurant** Collection with JSON format(SAMPLE)

```
"_id" : NumberLong(1),
  name : "Dominos Pizza"
```

Menu Collection:-
Document1 related to restaurant "_id":1 name: Dominos

```
"_id" : NumberLong(32),
"active" : true,
"name"   : "Pizza Menu",
  ........,
"restaurant" : DBRef("restaurant", NumberLong(1)),
"systemName" : "1menu",
"version" : NumberLong(2),
"displayOrder" : null
```

Document 2 related to restaurant "_id":1 name: Dominos :-

```
"_id" : NumberLong(32),
"active" : true,
"name"   : "Burger Menu",
  ........,
"restaurant" : DBRef("restaurant", NumberLong(1)),
"systemName" : "1menu",
"version" : NumberLong(2),
"displayOrder" : null
```

Document 2 related to restaurant "_id":1 name: Dominos

```
"_id" : NumberLong(36),
"active" : true,
"name"   : "Dessert Menu",
  ........,
"restaurant" : DBRef("restaurant", NumberLong(1)),
"systemName" : "1menu",
"version" : NumberLong(2),
"displayOrder" : null
```

Question:- 
How Could i (get) Query all the Menus Realted to the restaurant 1(dominos)
by Using  DBRef("restaurant", NumberLong(1))?
Thanks For the Help in advance !!!
Hope some One answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 db.menu.find({"restaurant.$id": 1})
```